# My app stops working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a basic application which contains two activities. Both contain a TextView showing the title and the first one contains an EditText in which the user types a message and clicks on a button on its side, the second activity is launched which shows the message the user types.

It has the following problem:

1.When I click on the button, the app stops saying "Unfortunately Write n Display and stopped.", rather than launching the second activity at all.

**The Logcat can be found here:** [enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/udaZ7VNS) since adding it to the question exceeded the limit.

CODE OF FIRST ACTIVITY: -

```
package com.practice.myfirstapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String key_name="com.practice.firstApp.key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1_MainActivity);
        String key_value= editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(key_name, key_value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

LAYOUT OF FIRST ACTIVITY: -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView1_MainActivity"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:text="@string/title_MainActivity"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1_MainActivity"


        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1_MainActivity"

        android:hint="@string/EditText_MainActivity"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TextView1_MainActivity"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/EditText1_MainActivity"

        android:text="@string/Button_MainActivity"

        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE OF SECOND ACTIVITY: -

```
package com.practice.myfirstapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String intent_value= intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.key_name);

        TextView textView= new TextView(this);
        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2_SecondActivity);

        textView.setText(intent_value);

    }
}
```

LAYOUT OF SECOND ACTIVITY: -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:text="@string/title_SecondActivity"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2_SecondActivity"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

STRINGS RESOURCE FILE:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Write n Display</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string name="title_MainActivity">WRITE</string>
    <string name="EditText_MainActivity">Your Message here</string>

    <string name="Button_MainActivity">Send</string>

    <string name="title_SecondActivity">DISPLAY</string>

</resources>
```

ANDROID MANIFEST FILE: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.practice.myfirstapp1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.practice.myfirstapp1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.practive.myfirstapp1.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: first, for the logcat issue go back to Java then follow, window -> show view -> other -> Logcat.. and it will be available with the console tab... try it out and if it is successful, add the errors to the code.

Comment: @OsamaEspil It is the same: : E/(): Device disconnected: 1

Comment: disconnect your device and connect it again and paste the logcat details.

Comment: I have edited the question and added a link to the LogCat results, since pasting them here exceeded the permissible length of the question. @nOiAd

Answer (score 1):

To solve your first issue: put below code to your  textview of both xml files.

**Reason**: You had not put the `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in your TextView

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:text="@string/title_MainActivity"
```

To solve your second issue:Change LAYOUT OF FIRST ACTIVITY:

**Reason**: android:layout_width is "0dp". it should be wrap_content or fill_parent or match_parent

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText1_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1_MainActivity"
    android:hint="@string/EditText_MainActivity"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

To:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText1_MainActivity" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" //you can put, fill_parent or match_parent
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1_MainActivity"
    android:hint="@string/EditText_MainActivity"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

To solve your third issue: change your  CODE OF FIRST ACTIVITY: -

**Reason**: You had put  editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1_MainActivity); in sendMessage(View view). send message contains a `View` so whenever you initiate any component in this method, it will search that component on this particular view which is incorrect. you can initiate your components in any method which does not contain any view parameter.if you want to initiate any component in particular view then you have to initiate it like editText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditText1_MainActivity);. But in your case edittext is in main view so you need to remove it from sendMessage(View view).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String key_name="com.practice.firstApp.key";
  EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1_MainActivity);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

        String key_value= editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(key_name, key_value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Change your second Activity

**Reason**:  TextView textView= new TextView(this); is not correct way to initialize any component of your xml view.

```
TextView textView= new TextView(this);
textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2_SecondActivity);
textView.setText(intent_value);
```

To:

```
    TextView textView;
    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2_SecondActivity);
    textView.setText(intent_value);
```

Comment: This has displayed the EditText in the first activity. But please tell me what was wrong in putting creating EditText in sendMessage(). Should I learn from it that all the GUI elements have to be created in the onCreate(), although they can be manipulated later in other methods?

Secondly the second activity is still not launching, the app stops. Can you please help me with that too?

Comment: Please, Post your logcat. debug the sendMessage(View view).is this method calling or not? have u declare your second class to manifest?

Comment: The answer to the first and second questions resolved the first and second problems. Thank you.The answers to the third question didn't help it:
 1. The application still stops before opening the second activity at all.
 2. This is a tutorial to a 99% similar application: [link] (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) They have initialized the editText in sendMessage() and I did it just the same way (see the code in section - coninued in the next comment!

Comment: continued from previous comment - section 'Start the Second Activity'), and they have initialized the text view by TextView textView = new TextView(this); in the second activity's code. I am editing my question, with the tweaks which helped, and the logcat can be found here: [link](http://pastebin.com/udaZ7VNS) since posting it here exceeded the length of the question. I'll be grateful for your guidance and help.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve your problem like this

1.replace

`android:gravity="center_horizontal"` by `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`.

2.Give layout_width as `wrap_content` for edittext of first activity xml

3.Make your `sendMessage` method public not private

To get the logcat In Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.

**OR**

Write `LogCat` in `Quick Access` edit box in your eclipse window (top right corner, just before Open Prospective button). And just select LogCat it will open-up the LogCat window in your current prospec[image]

Comment: Changing sendMessage() to public did not help me in any way apparently, but yes it is shown public in the example code in tutorials, and you're saying that too, so can you please tell me why does it have to be public? Is anything outside the class accessing it?

Comment: I think it is being accessed from layout ofcourse, which is in a subclass of R.java, which is a part of the package named android in the android framework. Is that why you say it should be public? If that is the case, I wonder why doesn't the compiler complain on it?

Comment: Thank you for telling me the easy way to open LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

change `private void sendMessage(View view)` to `public void sendMessage(View view)` (private to public)

LAYOUT OF FIRST ACTIVITY:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView1_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+string/title_MainActivity"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText1_MainActivity"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/EditText_MainActivity"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button_MainActivity"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

LAYOUT OF SECOND ACTIVITY: -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">

<TextView 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+string/title_SecondActivity"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView2_SecondActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: ` android:gravity="center_vertical" ` gives the error saying String types not allowed (at 'gravity' with value 'center_vertical')

Comment: OK the error is gone now. But after your tweaks, nothing has happened except that all the widgets in the first activity have come in the centre of the screen. I did not want that but it doesn't matter.
The important thing is that the second activity is still now displaying. The app stops before that.

Comment: Ensure you changed private void sendMessage(View view) to public void sendMessage(View view).

Comment: I did. I think you have tried to run the code yourself. Does it work fine at your end?

Comment: After a few tweaks, it has improved, I have edited the code and problems in my question. But the app still stops before the second activity comes up. you can see the logcat here: [link](http://pastebin.com/udaZ7VNS)

Comment: declare SecondActivity as public. (class SecondActivity to public class SecondActivity)...

Answer (score 0):

**Logcat shows the following:**

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.practice.myfirstapp1/com.practice.myfirstapp1.SecondActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

You did define SecondActivity in manifest, but the package name is wrong (            *android:name="com.practive.myfirstapp1.SecondActivity" should be ndroid:name="com.practice.myfirstapp1.SecondActivity"*
).

```
<activity
            android:name="com.practice.myfirstapp1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.practive.myfirstapp1.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

It should be

```
<activity
            android:name="com.practice.myfirstapp1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.practice.myfirstapp1.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I did it, and the problem is still there.